# TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "black.gif" I do not understand why the error appears to me even though the file type is GIF

Tags: python, python-turtle

```
import turtle
def choos():
 listo=['brown.gif','black.gif','green.gif','pink.gif']
 n=turtle.Screen()
 n.bgcolor("white")
 for i in listo:
        n.addshape(i)

        turtle.shape(i)
        turtle.stamp()
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.fd(100)
        turtle.pendown()
 first=turtle.textinput("title","choose  color for  Screen:\n")
 if first not in listo:
 #
        turtle.write("no")     
        turtle.hideturtle()


choos()
```

the error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-0610edf520c4> in <module>
     18 
     19 
---> 20 choos()

<ipython-input-36-0610edf520c4> in choos()
      4      n.bgcolor("white")
      5      for i in listo:
----> 6             n.addshape(f"{i}")
      7 
      8             turtle.shape(i)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\turtle.py in register_shape(self, name, shape)
   1131             # image
   1132             if name.lower().endswith(".gif"):
-> 1133                 shape = Shape("image", self._image(name))
   1134             else:
   1135                 raise TurtleGraphicsError("Bad arguments for register_shape.\n"

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\turtle.py in _image(filename)
    477         imagedata from a gif-file named filename.
    478         """
--> 479         return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename)
    480 
    481     def __init__(self, cv):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, cnf, master, **kw)
   4059         Valid resource names: data, format, file, gamma, height, palette,
   4060         width."""
-> 4061         Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
   4062 
   4063     def blank(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, imgtype, name, cnf, master, **kw)
   4004                 v = self._register(v)
   4005             options = options + ('-'+k, v)
-> 4006         self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
   4007         self.name = name
   4008 

TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "black.gif"
```

I try here in the code that it will show the user images in different colors and he will have to choose one of them so that the selected image will be the image of the screen, I looked almost everywhere on the internet for the mistake but they always say convert it to a GIF file even though it has been converted
I added here the pictures which should appear to the user
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you use any converter or just changed the extension name

Comment: Yes. Obviously. I created brand new GIFs and added them to the list in the program.

Comment: Does any other GIF work?

Comment: What do you mean by another GIF works? Do you mean that the other GIF files in this list are working? if so, only the first item in the list is working, but the rest isn't working and I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe not properly converted, try converting it again or use `png` images?

Comment: I used in png files first. But  it didn't work

Comment: I tried what you said and it isn't working

Comment: Maybe the issue is something else, you can wait for better answers.